# How will PEAQ tokens interact with IOTA and the Tangle?

Tags: transaction, economics, peaq

PEAQ is a new platform that will be developed on top of IOTA and the Tangle that will allow for tokenization, similar to the ERC-20 standard of Ethereum.

With it's launch we will likely see several new tokens pop up that are built on top of the Tangle.

However, it is unclear how this will impact the Tangle, and how it will interact with IOTA. Will tokens fully rely on IOTA transactions to occur, or only tangle activity (such as 0 iota transaction, which means IOTA is cut out of the picture)? What is the possibility that some token becomes more useful/popular than the original IOTA token?

Comment: This question could greatly benefit from some sort of reference to any PEAQ *thing*.

Comment: How will Peaq ensure persistence of those tokens? Permanode? or other sort of database to feed-in the values after a snapshot?

Comment: Tokens don’t just have the use case to be a useful payment. You can think of it like stocks of a startup. Most erc20 tokens are also no real payment tokens they just give you a part from the cake

Comment: IMO, this is a somewhat speculative question even today, 5 months after it was asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source of information: mainly [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQEsItb922k) [presentations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SY6BG5V2CHQ) of the project. The white-paper presenting the Peaq project in details is currently under review, but should be available in december. (1/12/2017)

---

Creating a token with Peaq consist of a single transaction on the tangle were you declare the total amount of token.
The data of the Peak protocol is embedded in tangle transactions. To ensure data integrity (i.e. no double spend of those new tokens): every peaq transaction relies on 3 tangle transactions. 
The current plan is that those 3 transactions will be zero-iota transactions ([source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQEsItb922k#t=1h25m)) simply because there is no reason for that.

The peaq team expect that this project will bring many new users on the tangle... and so increasing the speed and security of the network.

> What is the possibility that some token becomes more useful/popular
>   than the original IOTA token?

Difficult to say. IMO it mainly depends of the marketing effort done to sell one of those new token.